# only date and only time in same column - sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a web portal  that should display only time if the date is today's date otherwise it should display date .

```
dossier_date_created       |   Expected result
----------------------------------------------------
2013-10-22 16:18:46.610    |     2013-10-22
2013-10-23 11:26:56.390    |     11:26
```

I tried something like this :

```
select 
case 
when CONVERT(date,dossier_date_created) = CONVERT(DATE,getdate()) then convert(char(5), dossier_date_created, 108) 
else convert(date, dossier_date_created) 
end as timedate
 from Proj_Manage_Dossier
```

But the result was :

```
     timedate
    -----------
    2013-10-22
    1900-01-01
```

How can I do it only with SQL? And btw Datatype of my column "dossier_date_created" is `datetime`

Comment: What **version** of SQL Server?? **2008** and newer have `DATE` and `TIME` datatypes that would perfectly suit your needs

Comment: Use `CAST(... AS DATE)` to get the date only, and `CAST(... AS TIME)` for the time only ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `CAST` or `CONVERT` to get your values to `DATE` or `TIME` datatypes. But, since you can't combine two data types in same column you have to cast them both to something identical - like `NVARCHAR` afterwards:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(dossier_date_created AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
            THEN CAST(CAST (dossier_date_created AS TIME) AS NVARCHAR(10))
    ELSE CAST(CAST(dossier_date_created AS DATE) AS NVARCHAR(10)) END
FROM dbo.Proj_Manage_Dossier
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/564d9/1)**

**EDIT** - For SQL Server versions older then 2008, where there are no DATE and TIME datatypes - You can also directly `CONVERT` to `VARCHAR` [using appropriate style codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),dossier_date_created,102) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),GETDATE(),102)
            THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),dossier_date_created,108)
    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),dossier_date_created,102) END
FROM dbo.Proj_Manage_Dossier
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/505d6/1)**

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
    select 
      case 
      when (CONVERT(date,PaymentDate) = CONVERT(DATE,getdate()))
       then convert(VARCHAR(15), PaymentDate, 108) 
      else convert(varchar, PaymentDate, 101) 
      end as timedate
    from Payments
```

Hope it will help you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
select case when cast(dossier_date_created as date) = cast(getdate() as date) 
    then cast(cast(dossier_date_created as time) as varchar)
    else cast(cast(dossier_date_created as date) as varchar)
    end from #Proj_Manage_Dossier
```

Hope it helps :)

cheers......